# generate a permutation without same element adjacent

Tags: python, permutation

I am working on a leetcode question [767. Reorganize String](https://leetcode.com/problems/reorganize-string/), there are many good answers to it. But I am eager to know where has gone wrong in my own code (learning from my own mistake is also important for preventing similar mistakes in the future). My idea is to generate permutation one by one, and check the result on the fly whether there are two same elements adjacent, if so, then jump to the next permutation, soon as there is one good permutation my code stops. My code failed at  27 / 62 due to Time Limit Exceeded. I don't know why my code takes milliseconds to get a correct permutation for a very long string but take a very long time to handle a much shorter string.

```
def permutations(S,path):
    if len(path)==length:
        return "".join(path)
    for i in range(len(S)):
        if path and S[i]==path[-1]:
            continue
        else:
            p= permutations(S[:i]+S[i+1:],path+[S[i]])
            if p:
                return p
```

**input 1**

```
S ="kkkkzraaaaaaaaaakatkwpkkkktrbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbqasffffffffffdffwsssrrrefffdddrgerterg"
path = []
length = len(S)
permutations(S,path)
```

It takes milliseconds to generate a correct permutation.

**input 2**

```
S = "bbbbaaaaababaababab"
path = []
length = len(S)
permutations(S,path)
```

It takes an extremely long time to handle this string.

Could you please help me understand where I have done wrong or misunderstood?

Comment: Without looking at the details, it looks like you've been lucky to generate a valid permutation quickly with the first input, and that you haven't (or that it's impossible to find one) with the second. Note that for a "short" string of 19 characters, there are 19! = more than 10^17 possible permutations. You need a different strategy than generating them until you find a working one...

Comment: Yes, Sir. For the worst scenarios, my code still has a time complexity of O(n!), even though it can skip lots of permutations and stop earlier. I guess input 2 is one of the worst scenarios for my code. Thank you very much for your great help.